# Add provided dependency to test classpath using Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I've `provided` dependency scope configured like below. My problem is, the provided dependencies are not visible during runtime in tests. How can I configure this to keep the dependencies `provided` but available on the test classpath?

```
apply plugin: 'java'

configurations {
    provided
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath += configurations.provided
    }
}

dependencies {
    provided 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    provided 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'

    // Tests
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.assertj:assertj-core:1.7.0'

    // Additional test compile dependencies
    testCompile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.2'
}
```

One solution  is to add the dependency like the joda-time library with `testCompile` scope, but I don't want to duplicate any entries. I'm sure it can be achieved with proper configuration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two ways to do this. First, have the `testRuntime` configuration extend from `provided`.

```
configurations {
    provided
    testRuntime.extendsFrom(provided)
}
```

Second, you could add the `provided` configuration to the classpath of your `test` task.

```
test {
    classpath += configurations.provided
}
```

Comment: Even using both configurations I still cannot run tests. For example using Joda Time with provided and no matter which configuration I get `Gradle: error: package org.joda.time does not exist`

Comment: Are these compile or runtime dependencies. If it is a compile dependency you will need to specify as you did in your original post with `sourceSets.test.compileClasspath += configurations.provided`.

Comment: Still doesn't work. It compiles but during runtime I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant` Tried with the options posted in answer and the only change is with  `testRuntime.extendsFrom(provided)` but still crashes with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: junit/textui/ResultPrinter` Any ideas?

Comment: Added `testCompile.extendsFrom(provided)` to the `configurations` and works perfectly. Do you know whether such config is proper or may cause other issues?

Comment: Your jar is a compile time requirement so yes, it needs to be on **both** the compile and runtime classpath. That can be accomplished with the answer you added, or by adding it to the sourceSet classpath **and** the `test` task classpath. Both solutions are roughly equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed with one additional line in `configurations`. Don't know if it's the best and a proper solution but works as intended.

```
configurations {
    provided
    testCompile.extendsFrom(provided)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### my case

```kotlin
withType<Jar> {
    enabled = true
    isZip64 = true
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

    archiveFileName.set("$project.jar")

    from(sourceSets.main.get().output)
    dependsOn(configurations.compileClasspath)
    from({
        configurations.compileClasspath.get().filter {
            it.name.endsWith("jar")
        }.map { zipTree(it) }
    }) {
        exclude("META-INF/*.RSA", "META-INF/*.SF", "META-INF/*.DSA")
    }
}
```